# Getting time from a Date Object

Tags: java, date, time

I have an date object from which i need to `getTime()`. The issue is it always shows `00:00:00`.

```
SimpleDateFormat localDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
long date = Utils.getDateObject(DateObject).getTime();
String time = localDateFormat.format(date);
```

Why is the time always `'00:00:00'`. Should i append `Time to my Date Object`

Comment: How are you initializing `DateObject`? Also, please follow Java naming conventions; it should be `dateObject` and not `DateObject`.

Comment: What is `Utils.getDateObject()`?

Comment: Poor question. You have "DateObject" and "Utils.getDateObject.getTime" both of which are mysteries.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should pass the actual `Date` object into `format`, not a `long`:

```
SimpleDateFormat localDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
String time = localDateFormat.format(Utils.getDateObject(DateObject));
```

Assuming that whatever `Utils.getDateObject(DateObject)` is actually returns a `Date` (which is *implied* by your question but not actually stated), that should work fine.

For example, this works perfectly:

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class SDF {
    public static final void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleDateFormat localDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        String time = localDateFormat.format(new Date());
        System.out.println(time);
    }
}
```

---

Re your comment below:

> Thanks TJ, but actually i am still getting 00:00:00 as time.

That means your `Date` object has zeroes for hours, minutes, and seconds, like so:

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class SDF {
    public static final void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleDateFormat localDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        String time = localDateFormat.format(new Date(2013, 4, 17)); // <== Only changed line (and using a deprecated API)
        System.out.println(time);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks TJ, but actually i am still getting 00:00:00 as time.

Comment: @theJava: Then the date object has zeroes for hours, minutes, and seconds.

Comment: At this case what should we do, i am entering a date in front-end, today's date... but why am i not getting the time from it.

Comment: @theJava: What time would you expect? If you're just entering a date, should the code pick a time at random? Choose noon? 3:15 p.m.?

Comment: That's where i am struck, should the date object by default carry time along with it... i am just confused...

Comment: @theJava: **It does**. It's just that since you're only initializing it with a date, it's defaulting to midnight, which is the only reasonable default. Seriously, again, what are you expecting it to do?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30084/discussion-between-thejava-and-t-j-crowder)

Comment: @theJava: I don't do the SO chat thing when it's relevant to the question or answer. (Frankly I think it's stupid except as a cool place to hang out.)

Answer (score 3):

Apart from above solution , you can also use calendar class if you don't have specific requirement

```
Calendar cal1 =new GregorianCalendar() or Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat date_format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println(date_format.format(cal1.getTime()));
```

Answer (score 3):

For example, you can use next code:

```
 public static int getNotesIndexByTime(Date aDate){
    int ret = 0;
    SimpleDateFormat localDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH");
    String sTime = localDateFormat.format(aDate);
    int iTime = Integer.parseInt(sTime);
    return iTime;// count of hours 0-23
 }
```